# c++ access private data of the class

Tags: c++

I can't figure what I am doing wrong? I have a class, which has private data:

```
static const int SIZE = 101;
int *ptr;
int set [SIZE];
```

And I have 2 constructors. One is a default constructor that set array to 0.
And other one that takes 5 arguments and set 5 values in the array to 1.
I need to print this array. When I am in constructor everything is working, when I do cout << inside the constructor result is correct. But when I am trying to use function print. Result is garbage. What I am doing wrong?

```
IntegerSet::IntegerSet() //default constructor
{
    int set[SIZE] = {0};
    ptr = set;
    cout << "Default Constructor: " << endl;
    for (int i =0; i<SIZE ;i++)
    {
        cout << set[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


IntegerSet::IntegerSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    int set[SIZE] = {0};
    ptr = set;

    ptr[a] = ptr[b] = ptr[c] = ptr[d] = ptr[e] = 1;

    cout << "Constructor with 5 parametrs: " << endl;
    for (int i =0; i<SIZE ;i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void IntegerSet::print() const
{
    bool flag = false;
    cout << "I am in print: " << endl;

    for (int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if (ptr[i]==1)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
        cout << "-----";
    cout << endl;
}


void main()
{
    IntegerSet s1;
    IntegerSet s2(1,50,10,22,98);

    s2.print();
}
```

Comment: Its garbage because set was on the stack so the pointer (ptr) will not be valid when you exit the constructor.

Comment: Use a vector instead and do not redeclare it in the constructor.

Comment: is it any other options so I can continue with array? I never used vector before

Comment: Show us your `main` please.

Comment: @user2001019 please accept an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each of your constructors declares a new array called `set` which shadows the class member.

Comment: if I change this     int set[SIZE] = {0}; ptr = set; to this  set[SIZE] = 0; ptr = set; The result is correct, but I have error: stack the variable was corrupted..

Comment: @user2001019 you need to put `set()` in the constructor initialization list. You can't assign to plain arrays.

Comment: Since `set` only has `SIZE` members, `set[SIZE]` is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting ptr to set that is defined in your constructor and not the set that is the class variable. change the following in your constructor :

```
int set[SIZE] = {0};
ptr = set;
```

to

```
set[SIZE-1] = {0};
ptr = set;
```

Comment: should be `set[SIZE-1] = {0};` then

Comment: @helb Why `SIZE - 1`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 because an array with SIZE number of elements can only be index with 0, 1, ... SIZE-1. Example: If you have `int set[3]` then you can access the 3 elements in the array with set[0], set[1] and set[2]. If you try accessing set[3] the resulting pointer is outside of your array bounds.

Comment: @helb Maybe he didn't want to set the value at the last index to 0, but rather wanted to set the entire *contents* of the array to 0.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yeah, maybe. Then i would use `memset(set, 0, SIZE*sizeof(int));` or `std::fill_n(set, SIZE, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19550820/701092), here is my suggestion related to the quality and maintainablity of your code. You should be using a container such as `std::array` for compile-time arrays, and also the member-initializer list for the initialization of your data members.

Your were under the misapprehension that the following line of code set the contents of `set` to 0.

```
int set[SIZE] = {0};
```

When rather it overshadows the private data member `set` in the `IntegerSet` class and creates a local variable in the constructor. This is one of the reasons why you should be using STL containers for these feats. For example:

```
#include <array> // for std::array

class IntegerSet
{
private:
    std::array<int, 101> set;
public:
    IntegerSet()
        : set() // zero-initializes each element
    {
        for (auto val : set)
            std::cout << val " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    IntegerSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
        : set()
    {
        set[a] = set[b] = set[c] = set[d] = set[e] = 1;

        for (auto val : set)
            std::cout << val " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You put `int set[SIZE] = {0};` in the constructor as well, which defines a local `set` on the stack (this 'shadows' the private member variable which is also called `set`).

In case you're trying to do `set[SIZE] = 0` (set the last element of set to 0) then you have a second mistake: You are accessing `set` out of bounds (arrays in C and C++ are 0-indexed. So an array of size 5 has valid index (0, 1, 2, 3 and 4)). You should do `set[SIZE-1] = 0`. Or better yet, use `std::vector` or `std::array` (C++11) instead of C-style arrays.

Answer (score 0):

array `set` is local to the constructor . Hence the pointer `ptr` which points to the `set` ,later points to NULL as the array `set` does not exist when the control goes out of the constructor .

Use the array `set` which is instance variable so that you have the same instance of `set` in both the constructors as well as in the `print` method .

```
IntegerSet::IntegerSet()                                            //default constructor
{
    set[SIZE-1] = {0};
    ptr = set;
    cout << "Default Constructor: " << endl;
    for (int i =0; i<SIZE ;i++)
    {
        cout << set[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


IntegerSet::IntegerSet(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    set[SIZE-1] = {0};
    ptr = set;

    ptr[a] = ptr[b] = ptr[c] = ptr[d] = ptr[e] = 1;

    cout << "Constructor with 5 parametrs: " << endl;
    for (int i =0; i<SIZE ;i++)
    {
        cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation for your garbage output:

```
ptr[a] = ptr[b] = ptr[c] = ptr[d] = ptr[e] = 1;
// ...
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << ptr[i] << " ";
}
```

In your main method, you used the arguments 1, 50, 10, 22, and 98. So the first line in the above example is equivalent to:

```
ptr[1] = ptr[50] = ptr[10] = ptr[22] = ptr[98] = 1;
```

and there's nothing wrong with that. The problem is what happens below it. In your `for()` loop you're attempting to iterate over `ptr` from its first index (`0`) to `SIZE`. You've only given the values for 5 places in the array, so the others are uninitialized. This is causing Undefined Behavior for your program and is the reason for the garabage output.

You should print the values using the indexes separately.

But until you can tell us what the reason is for you doing this, I can't suggest a better alternative method.

Comment: because I set array whole array to 0 before, then I change 5 element to 1

Comment: `ptr = set` doesn't assign `ptr` a copy of `set`. The thing is, `set` *decays* from an array to a pointer, so the zero-initialization of `set` doesn't apply to `ptr`.